# Lead assignment round robin based on lead source

Tags: trigger, assignment-rules

i want to implement round robin for lead assignment but it should only work based on a lead source value . only should run when lead source is equal to facebook .

can any one suggest me what would be the best approach to do this  ?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement standard round robin assignment, as prescribed by Salesforce here:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004000

But make sure that in the formula field called "Round_Robin_ID" you include a filter for the Lead source.

```
IF(text(LeadSource)='Facebook',MOD(VALUE(Lead_Number__c) ,3) + 1, 0)
```